# Leaking water hose 99 mazda 626

Tags: cooling-system, mazda

[image]

What hose is this? Leaking water 
99 Mazda 626

Answer (score 1):

Its likely only Mazda will have a specific name or part number for it. However I would normally label a hose by where it goes from and to e.g. The "water pump to thermostat housing hose". As this hose looks pretty short & straightish though you'll likely be able to buy a peice of suitable hose. Just make sure its internal diameter is the correct size.

Comment: It may be one of the pipes to the heater, but the answer is more than fine.